# Testing for primitive roots using quadratic non residue and Jacobi symbol

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues, primitive-roots, legendre-symbol

Is this always true for all cases??

$a$ is a primitive root $modulo$ $n$ $⇒$  $\left(\dfrac{a}{n}\right) = -1$

Is the converse also always true?

$\left(\dfrac{a}{n}\right)$ $= -1$ $⇒$ $a$ is a primitive root modulo n.

So if I'm testing for a primitive root modulo n then all I have to do is just evaluate the Jacobi symbol?

Comment: Do you mean the Jacobi symbol?  Or are you taking $n$ to be a prime?

Comment: Yes Jacobi. No n doesn't have to be prime

Comment: To your second question, Consider $6\pmod 7$  It's not a square but it is a cube, and since $3\,|\,(7-1)$ no cube could be a primitive root.  (more simply, $6^2\equiv 1 \pmod 7$).

Comment: You're asking whether or not 6 is a primitive root modulo 7?

Comment: I am pointing out that it isn't, which disproves your proposed converse.

Comment: Alright so in general if I'm testing if a number $a$ is a primitive root modulo n then it doesn't suffice to just calculate the Jacobi symbol, because the Jacobi symbol might equal -1 but $a$ still might not be a primitive root mod n?

Comment: Correct. And for (some) composite numbers you can have a primitive root with Jacobi symbol $1$.  I have posted a (trivial) example below.

Answer (score 1):

For both questions, the answer is No.

For the first, note that $2$ is a primitive root $\pmod 9$ but $$\left(\frac 29\right)=\left(\frac 23\right)^2=(-1)^2=1$$

For the second, note that $-1$ is not a square $\pmod 7$ and neither is it a primitive root.

Comment: Is there a special case where  ($a$ is a primitive root $modulo$ $n$ $⇒$  $\left(\dfrac{a}{n}\right) = -1$) is ALWAYS true? Because I've read this result being quoted elsewhere and I was asking the question to sort of find out when is the result true. It seems it is always true for when n is an odd prime perhaps?

Comment: Certainly true for odd primes (all powers of a square are also squares).  Otherwise...well, there aren't very many other cases in which primitive roots exist.  Really just prime powers and $2$ times prime powers.